# How to reduce Spring boot applications memory usage with embedded tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-management

I tried to run 7 services (spring boot apps - JAR files) on same system/server. Each app was taken 500 MB of memory. 
Each spring boot contains the following:

```
Eureka Client
Data JPA
AMQP (RabbitMQ)
Web, Webmvc
Actuator
Test
Devtools
```

After research in google/SO, i have used JAVA_OPTS to restrict heap size and stack size like below:

```
java -Xmx64m -Xss256k -jar test.jar
```

now the memory reduced to 200 MB. But its UP and Down without load i.e., in idle time also.

I have few questions here:
Is there any other way to reduce more memory?

Is there any way to check which component/dependency is taking more memory?

Is it because of embedded tomcat server?

If I export the war file and deployed it on JBoss/Tomcat, will the memory reduce?

Comment: Change the default configs to reduce Jersey handler threads, IO threads, decrease connection pool size, etc...

Comment: Also you can use JMX (or some other Tomcat tools) to analyze where memory is being allocated and check configuration for those.

Comment: @Hitobat can you please provide me those default properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, removing things that should not be deployed like `Actutator`, `Test` and `Devtools` would reduce memory footrpint for sure...